# Python - Scoring a list of words using a dictionary of Scrabble letter values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, scrabble

Sorry if this is easy all, I'm brand new to coding.

I'm given a list of words, i.e.

```
my_words = [ 'Apple", 'banana', 'Grape', 'orange' ]
```

I'm also given a dictionary of letter values,

```
letter_value = {'a':1 , 'b':3, 'c':3, 'd':2, 'e':1, 'f':4. 'g':2, 'h':4, 'i':1, 'j':8, 'k':5, 'l':1, 'm':3, 'n':1. 'o':1, 'p':3, 'q':10, 'r':1, 's':1, 't':1, 'u':1, 'v':8, 'w':4, 'x':8, 'y':4, 'z':10}
```

I have to

> create a function that takes a word and computes the scrabble score for that word, which I did:

```
def scrabblescore(words): 
     total = 0
     for letter in word: 
         total += letter_value[letters]
     return total
```

when I try it out, `print(scrabblescore("myscore")` it is working properly

What I don't know how to do is

> write a function that will take the whole list of words, iterate over the list, and use the first function to compute the score of each word in the list and make a dictionary such as

```
{'apple': 20, 'banana':10} etc.
```

Thanks in advance all

Comment: What is your question? How to write a loop? How to call a function? How to store the results in a dictionary?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is not acceptable.

Comment: Actually the statement of work is not hard to figure out and can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to put the full code here (that's for you to figure out) but I will give you what you should be doing.

1: Set up a dictionary variable.

2: Iterate through the values. For every word in my_words, do:

3: Iterate through the letters. For every letter in word in my_words, do:

4: Find the value for the key in the dictionary for the letter. Add it to a temporary variable.

5: Set the word as the key and the temporary variable as the value.

Answer (score 0):

First fix your method, regarding the name of the variables, and use `.lower()` to deal with uppercase letters

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    total = 0
    for letter in word:
        total += letter_value[letter.lower()]
    return total
```

Then for the list of word, you can either use a dict-comprehension or the classic for-loop

```
def scrabble_score_words(words):
    return {word: scrabble_score(word) for word in words}


def scrabble_score_words(words):
    result = {}
    for word in words:
        result[word] = scrabble_score(word)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a foreach character loop:

```
for element in string_name:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like:

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    total = 0
    for letter in word:
        # hit here
        # 1. added lower() to make the letter lowercase
        # 2. IMPORTANT use letter 
        total += letter_value[letter.lower()] 
    return total

def scrabble_score_list(words):
    """take a list of the words"""
    # Just a wrapper for the first function
    rd = {}
    for x in words:
        rd[x] = scrabble_score(x)
    return rd
```

Answer (score 0):

I love doing homework assignments.
I beg you to learn; not just copy.

```
""" Yet another SO homework assignment """

letter_value = {'a':1, 'b':3, 'c':3, 'd':2, 'e':1, 'f':4, 'g':2, 'h':4, 'i':1,
                'j':8, 'k':5, 'l':1, 'm':3, 'n':1, 'o':1, 'p':3, 'q':10, 'r':1,
                's':1, 't':1, 'u':1, 'v':8, 'w':4, 'x':8, 'y':4, 'z':10}


def scrabble_score(word):
    """
    For a specific word, calculate the scrabble score of that word.
    :returns: The numeric scrabble score of a word.
    """
    total = 0
    for letter in word.lower():
        total += letter_value[letter]
    return total


def scrabble_dict(word_list):
    """
    A function that will take the whole list of words, iterate over the list,
    and use the scrabblescore() to compute the score of each word in the list
    and make a dictionary like {'Apple': 20, 'Banana':10}
    """
    word_dict = {}
    for word in word_list:
        score = scrabble_score(word)
        word_entry = {word: score}
        word_dict.update(word_entry)

    return word_dict


def main():
    """ Test out the scrabble dictionary """
    scrabble_dictionary = {}
    word_set_1 = ['Apple', 'banana', 'Grape', 'orange']
    scrabble_dictionary.update(scrabble_dict(word_set_1))

    word_set_2 = ['Orange', 'Pear', 'Grape', 'Pineapple', 'Xerox']
    scrabble_dictionary.update(scrabble_dict(word_set_2))

    print(scrabble_dictionary)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```